# Tableau: Replace all patterns of date

Tags: tableau-api

I have a column `Contact` as shown below, where I wish to add the Number of days since the Call/Visit/Skype from today besides the dates in parenthesis.

[image]

```
Today: 10 Jan, 2023
```

*The desired output should be:*

```
Call 22 Dec, 22 (19 Days); Visit 28 Dec, 22 (13 Days); Skype 20 Dec, 22 (21 Days)    
Visit 18 Dec, 22 (23 Days); Skype 12 Dec, 22 (29 Days)    
Call 05 Nov, 22 (66 Days); Visit 14 Dec, 22 (27 Days); Skype 01 Oct, 22 (100 Days)
```

*My attempt:* 'Days since the contact' can be calculated like this. Following will give the number of days:

```
Today() - DATEPARSE('dd MMM, yy','22 Dec, 22')
```

Now, how to use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_additional.htm) or some other functon to replace all these dates in a loop and replace them with the date+Number of days?

Comment: I don't think you can obtain the desired output format as shown, however, there is a way to split it into 3 columns, is that acceptable for you ?

Comment: Well, I already have a solution, whereby creating 3 additional variables solved the problem. Just that it was an unelegant way from Python perspective. That's why I posted this Question. It seems that its not possible in Tableau.

Comment: why not concatenate 3 additional variables into one

Comment: I was looking for a solution where in one Calculated Field I could do it. I already have a solution by creating multiple 3 calculated fields. If you can do that in one, you can let me know.